# ArcREST updateDefinition changes some fields but not others

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcrest

I am updating the Layer Definition's of a number of feature layers hosted by ArcGIS online via the arcrest module in python(2.7). For certain fields we want "visible" to be false, and for some we want "editable" to be false. I am finding that when updating it, the changes to "visible" are happening for the relevant fields, but no fields are allowing "editable" to be changed to false. Is this a known bug? Any suggestions? these are views, do we need to change the source data first?

See my code:

```
import arcpy, arcrest
from arcresthelper import securityhandlerhelper
from arcresthelper import common

config = {'username': <user>, 'password': ,<pword>}
token = securityhandlerhelper.securityhandlerhelper(config)
admin = 
arcrest.manageorg.Administration(securityHandler=token.securityhandler)
content = admin.content
userInfo = content.users.user()
userInfo.folders
#views
mpID = "<id>"
inID = "<id>"
rwID = "<id>"
nwID = "<id>"
npID = "<id>"

idList =[inID,mpID,rwID,nwID,npID]


for featid in idList:
    item = admin.content.getItem(itemId=featid)
    service = arcrest.hostedservice.service.AdminFeatureService(item.url,token.securityhandler,initialize=False, proxy_url=None, proxy_port=None)
    layer = service.layers[0]
    fieldscopy = layer.fields

    for field in fieldscopy:
        if field["name"] in (<fields to turn of editing>):
            field["editable"] = False

    for field in fieldscopy:
        if field["name"] in (<fields to make non-visible>):
            field["visible"] = False

    updateDict = {"fields":fieldscopy}
    layer.updateDefinition(updateDict)
```